# Converting Base64 stream to file object without saving

Tags: node.js

In Node.js, I want to use a `Base64Stream` from one module and use it as a file in another.

I am getting email attachments from [`mail-listener2`](https://github.com/chirag04/mail-listener2) which return like this:

```js
{
  contentType: 'image/png',
  contentDisposition: 'attachment',
  transferEncoding: 'base64',
  generatedFileName: 'attachment.png',
  contentId: '4b07159b34f1287079d4bdf7e77bc295@mailparser',
  stream: Base64Stream {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    writable: true,
    checksum: Hash {
      _options: undefined,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: Hash {},
      [Symbol(kState)]: [Object]
    },
    length: 5245,
    current: '',
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
  },
  checksum: '8d8c71ac84d23f92e171922eb89e1271',
  length: 5245
}
```

I want to attach those to an email using [`gmail-send`](https://github.com/alykoshin/gmail-send) which expects `filepath`.

Do I have to save the attachment to disk? If so, how?

Or can I somehow convert it "in memory"?

I tried

```
base64Data = attachment.stream;
require("fs").writeFile("out.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

but got a 0-length file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are using to write the file is asynchronous so you need to resolve the promise to ensure the file write is successful. Alternatively you can do something synchronous like this

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
const base64Data = attachment.stream;
// Convert the base64 data to a buffer
const buffer = Buffer.from(base64Data, 'base64')
// Set a path for the temporary file
const tempFilePath = '~/some/place/somewhere/file.extension'
// Write the raw buffer to a file synchronously 
fs.writeFileSync(tempFilePath, buffer)
// TODO Do your stuff using the file, then delete the temporary file

fs.unlink(tempFilePath, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
})
```

Its hard to tell if it can be done in memory without looking at the specific module youre using, but this way would work with the file path.